# Serialize object in increments?

Tags: c#, serialization, arrays

I know how to serialize an object into a byte array, but it serializes it as a whole, is there a way to serialize it in chunks of say, a kb? For example, I have an object, that would serialize into a large byte array of say 4mb, instead of serializing the whole object at the same time, I want to serialize it 1 kb chunk at a time, so it would serialize 1kb worth and pass it on, then move on to the next one until it is completely serialized. How might I go about doing this?

My current serialization/de-serialization class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

namespace TCP_Handler
{
    public class SerialMediator
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes a packet into a byte array
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pkt"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Byte[] Serialize(Packet pkt)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, (Object)pkt);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes a packet from a byte array
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arr"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Packet Deserialize(Byte[] arr)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            try
            {
                return (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw new Exception("Byte array did not represent a packet");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in using `byte[]`. Use a real stream (not a MemoryStream) and it is split up in the  channel as a matter of course.

Comment: What do you mean? In the serialize or deserialize function? And if you mean just writing the result to a stream in the serialize function, it's still adding all of the bytes to ram, it's just passing them in increments, not actually serializing in increments.